# I am stuck at filter OpenCV/Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, filter

I am trying to learn filters in opencv and running this code. But the problem is that when ı run the code it gives me an almost dark image and warns me with

```
c:/Users/... (3).py:19: 
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars 
result[j,i,a]=int((image[j,i,a]+image[j,i-1,a]+image[j,i+1,a]+image[j+1,i,a]+image[j-1,i,a]+image[j+1,i+1,a]+image[j+1,i-1,a]+image[j-1,i-1,a]+image[j-1,i+1,a])/9).
```

And if I comment these out and run code with the lines working with `cv2.filter2d` method it gives me an almost white image. I mean, doesn't they have to do the same thing, and musn't that filter blur the image? Here's my code:

```
import cv2

image=cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\fazil\Desktop\c.png")
cv2.imshow("input",image)
cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.CV_8U)
# kernel=np.array([
#     [1,1,1],
#     [1,1,1],
#     [1,1,1]
# ],np.float32)
# image=cv2.filter2D(image,-1,kernel)
def blur(image):
    height,width,channel=image.shape
    result=np.zeros(image.shape,image.dtype)
    for j in range(1,height-1):
        for i in range(1,width-1):
            for a in range(channel):
                result[j,i,a]=int((image[j,i,a]+image[j,i-1,a]+image[j,i+1,a]+image[j+1,i,a]+image[j-1,i,a]+image[j+1,i+1,a]+image[j+1,i-1,a]+image[j-1,i-1,a]+image[j-1,i+1,a])/9)
    return result

cv2.imshow("output",blur(image))
cv2.imwrite(r"C:\Users\fazil\Desktop\output.png",image)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Do not post more than one time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter in opencv/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64763938/filter-in-opencv-python)